# Three.js : Very first setup...?

Tags: three.js

Can anyone explain a step by step, process how to install three-js and get started. The steps before the https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene" starts

I have downloaded the "**three.js-master.zip**" but I cannot figure out the part of:

"*Before you can use three.js, you need somewhere to display it. Save the following HTML to a file on your computer, along with a copy of three.js in the js/ directory, and open it in your browser*"

and where to paste 
Please explain as you would to a children class, because everything I've tried till now, I get no visual feedback.
ex.

1. Download three.js.master,
2. Create a folder and unzip previous zip inside,
3. Create a text Document name it "thisNAme" and save it.
4. Change its extension to html.
5. copy paste this code. 
   6..............

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a project folder anywhere you like.

   For example: `C:\Users\yourname\simple-threejs-setup` if you're using Windows.
2. Create another folder inside your project folder called `js`.

   In my example: `C:\Users\yourname\simple-threejs-setup\js`
3. Download the [three.js library](https://threejs.org/build/three.js) (right click and then "download link as..."). Save it in the `js` folder (`C:\...\simple-threejs-setup\js`)
4. Create a **new** file in your project folder and name it anything you like but change the extension to `.html`. I named it `spinning-cube.html`
5. Right click on the file and select "Open with...", then select you favorite text editor.
6. Paste in the content from the [Getting Started page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene) on the THREE.js documentation. Note the `<script src="js/three.js">` tag. This points to the THREE.js library you downloaded in the previous step.

Source extracted below:

**spinning-cube.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );

                cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

6. Save and close the file
7. Double click on the spinning-cube.html to open it in your default browser. Html files open with your default browser by default. But if you have changed this behaviour. You can open your preferred browser and then just drag the file and drop in inside.*